# Android. Не распознаются загуженные mp3

Tags: java, android, mp3, download

Добрый день! Возникла следующая проблема. Я загружаю по url некий mp3 файл. Файл нормально загружается, его можно воспроизвести. Но проблема вот в чем: при использовании практически любого плеера в Android он не видит эти самые загруженные файлы в папке, в которую те были сохранены. Это практически не зависит от самого плеера (не видит ни один плеер, кроме VLC). При этом если я загружаю то же самое mp3 с помощью сторонних программ, то все плееры их нормально обнаруживают. При этом эти загруженные моей программой mp3 нормально могут быть воспроизведены, если ткрывать их каким-нибудь файловым менеджером/ При этом файловые менеджеры их видят, но почему-то не могут прочесть информацию об mp3 тегах. Вот пример

Аудио, загруженное моей программой. Теги не отображаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот mp3 загруженная сторонней программой. У нее теги нормально отображаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загружаю mp3 я вот так, ничего вроде особенного

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {               
        InputStream inputStream =  null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutput =  null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]); 
            File file = new File(path);              
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int bufferLength = 0; 

            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

                while(isPaused) {
                    sleep();
                }

                if(isCancelled()) {                 
                    if(file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                    return null;
                }

                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                publishProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
            }

            if(totalSize > getFreeMemorySize()) {
            //if(true) {
                if(errorHandler != null)
                    errorHandler.onMemorySizeException();
                cancel(true);
            }                       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            int i = e.hashCode();
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {

                if(inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
                if(fileOutput != null)
                    fileOutput.close();    

            } catch (IOException e) {
                int i = e.hashCode();
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Теперь вопрос: что я делаю не так и как исправить этот код чтобы mp3шки загружались нормально и были видны плеерами?

Comment: Вообще, id3 теги находятся в общем контенте файла, так что возможен вариант, что в этом конкретном файле id3 тегов просто нет.

Comment: я может привел не совсем корректный пример. Просто если скачать тот же самый файл с помощью какого-нибудь стороннего приложения, то теги у него будут на месте и любой плеер его увидит и воспроизведет без проблем. А вот когда я загружаю файл своей программой, то у любого файла такие вот проблемы. ТО есть это не зависит от конкретных mp3 файлов

Comment: Хмм. Database ID напрягает. Сейчас погуглил, сказано, что у андроида есть база данных музыки, которую запрашивают плееры, а так как ты никуда не афишируешь, что скачал музыку, в ней информация и не появляется. На интерес - скачай какой-нибудь файл и перезагрузи телефон, если теги появятся, значит, нужно общаться с базой. Как - надо смотреть и читать, поскольку я в этом нуб.

Comment: да, теги появляются после перезагрузки

Comment: Тогда вот так (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250515/how-to-update-the-android-media-database) нужно выбрать ответ, подходящий под версию Андроида, куда разрабатываете приложение. Там пара трюков есть, судя по коду.

Comment: @Vesper ого интересно, буду смотреть! Спасибо!